# Specific identity involving gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

I was trying to obtain Bailey's hypergeometric summation formula relying on this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Arjun-Rathie/publication/240991047_A_NOTE_ON_GAUSS%27S_SECOND_SUMMATION_THEOREM_FOR_THE_SERIES_2_F_1_12/links/540f0ca10cf2d8daaad08b88/A-NOTE-ON-GAUSSS-SECOND-SUMMATION-THEOREM-FOR-THE-SERIES-2-F-1-1-2.pdf).
The formula is: 
$$_{2}F_{1}(a,1-a;c;\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{c}{2})\Gamma(\frac{c+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{c+a}{2})\Gamma(\frac{c-a+1}{2})}.$$ 
However, using Euler's hypergeometric transformation and Beta function, I've got the following: 
$$_{2}F_{1}(a,1-a;c;\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{2^{a-1} \Gamma(c) \Gamma(\frac{c+a-1}{2})}{\Gamma(c+a-1) \Gamma(\frac{c-a+1}{2})}.$$ 
I've checked those two expression for different values of $a$ and $c$ in Wolfram Alpha, and they seem to agree. I'm not very skillful with special functions, so I don't know how to prove that they're equal (or wrong?). 
I'd appreciate any help.
**Edit:** perhaps it requires a proper application of Legendre's duplication formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It follows from [Legendre's duplication formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html):
$$\Gamma(2z)=2^{2z-1}\frac{\Gamma(z)\Gamma\left(z+\frac12\right)}{\sqrt \pi}.$$
A direct application of the formula gives that
\begin{align*}
\frac{2^{a-1} \Gamma(c) \Gamma(\frac{c+a-1}{2})}{\Gamma(c+a-1) \Gamma(\frac{c-a+1}{2})}&=2^{a-1}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{c+a-1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{c-a+1}{2})}\cdot\frac{2^{c-1}\Gamma\left(\frac{c}2\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{c+1}2\right)\sqrt\pi}{2^{c+a-2}\Gamma\left(\frac{c+a-1}2\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{c+a-1+1}2\right)\sqrt\pi}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{c}{2})\Gamma(\frac{c+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{c+a}{2})\Gamma(\frac{c-a+1}{2})}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! I'd struggle on those few lines a lot

Comment: @serpens You're welcome. I'm glad to help! I had a similar experience. Do more practice and you will be more familiar with these special functions stuff. Cheers! :-)